# Erro ao Inserir MYSQL pela data grid view

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

o código é o seguinte, estou fazendo um insert a partir de valores de uma data grid view

```
                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvCON.Rows)
                {
                        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
                        cmd = conectabanco.CreateCommand();
                        if (row.IsNewRow) continue;
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdProd", row.Cells["Id"].Value);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QtdProd", row.Cells["Quantidade"].Value);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NomeProd", row.Cells["Nome"].Value);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PrecoUnitProd", row.Cells["R$ Unidade"].Value);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TotalListaConsu", row.Cells["Total"].Value);
                        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO listaconsumo(IdCon, IdProd, QtdProd, PrecoUnitProd, " +
                        "totalListaConsu)VALUES("+idconsumo+", @IdProd, @QtdProd, @NomeProd, @PrecoUnitProd, @totalListaConsu)";

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
```

O problema é que, ao executar o Sql, ele envia pro insert o valor "@IDProd" propriamente dito, em vez de ser substituído pelo valor da datagridview

Comment: Por favor, [edit] a pergunta e adicionar o código direto no corpo da mesma. O [pt.so] possui suporte nativo para os códigos, então evite postá-los como imagem. Faça o [tour] para aprender o básico de como funciona o site.

Comment: Obrigado, já alterado!

Comment: porque não coloca esse "+idconsumo+" como parametro tambem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeiro que a quantidade de `VALUES` está diferente da quantidade de colunas do 
`INSERT`, você não está informando a coluna para o campo `NomeProd`. E onde você pega `row.Cells["R$ Unidade"].Value` acredito que esse seja um nome inválido para coluna de um datagridview.

Verifique essas questões e dê um feedback aqui por favor

A utilização para acessar o valor da célula da linha, é 
`row.Cells[0].Value` onde 0 é o índice da coluna, ou
`row.Cells["key"].Value` onde `key` é o nome do objeto `DataGridViewColumn` e não o nome que aparece na tela. Você pode acessar direto pelo objeto `DataGridviewColumn` informando a propriedade Name. Ex:

`row.Cells[nomeDaColuna.Name].Value`

Outra coisa, na pergunta você falou que o campo @IDProd não estava funcionando, agora passou que o @NomeProd não está. Qual é o certo ?

Tente aí.

Comment: Arrumei a diferença de quantidade da values para ser igual a do insert, já o nome "R$ Unidade" é o mesmo em que se encontra na tela, portanto posso usá-la com este nome creio. Porém de certa forma persiste o problema, não atribui as informações da datagridview para o comando "@NomeProd". Sei que posso contornar o problema inserindo direto, sem isso de ficar adicionando parâmetro de comandos, porém já agradeço

Comment: Fiz o que disse, o erro ainda persiste. O erro "@NomeProd" ou "@IDProd" é o mesmo, em vez de ele substituir os valores da tela para enviar pro banco, ele envia da seguinte forma:
INSERT INTO listaconsumo(IdCon, IdProd, QtdProd, NomeProd, PrecoUnitProd, totalListaConsu)VALUES(20, "@IdProd", "@QtdProd"," @NomeProd", "@PrecoUnitProd", "@totalListaConsu")

Em vez de: 
INSERT INTO listaconsumo(IdCon, IdProd, NomeProd, QtdProd, PrecoUnitProd, totalListaConsu)VALUES(20, 2, 5, 7, 2, 5);

Até mesmo substitutindo pelo índice direto(row.cells[0]) ainda persiste.

Comment: ele está dando erro na hora do comando SQL ? onde você está vendo que ele está passando o comando dessa forma ? ele executa o comando com sucesso e você vê esses valores armazenados ?

Comment: Sim, no comando SQL os campos "@NomeProd", "@IdProd", etc.... vão sem valores da datagridview, ele não consegue adicionar o valor da datagrid view para a extensão "@NomeProd "por exemplo.

Comment: Se está dando erro no comando SQL, qual erro? Se não está dando erro, você vê esses valores `@NomeProd` armazenado dentro do banco ?

Comment: Não chego a ver estes valores porque ele simplesmente não faz esse comando de assimilação do "@NomeProd" ele simplesmente envia esse nome do que o valor que está na tela

Comment: Essa é minha pergunta, onde você está vendo que o comando não está indo com os valores?

Comment: Quando dou um breakpoint na linha "Execute non query" e vejo o insert, no caso o texto que ele está enviando pro banco, seria isso?

Comment: é assim mesmo, o MySqlCommand não vai substituir os valores dos parametros na query, ele vai executar com esses parâmetros, qm irá fazer isso é o driver de comunicação, no caso do Mysql. não dá pra você ver isso em tempo de execução colocando um break point

Comment: Entendo, pois quando eu uso ele de forma direta ( em vez de ficar criando comandos e parâmetros jogo cada row direto no insert ) consigo ver os valores no break point do código. Mesmo assim, muito obrigado!

Comment: apesar de ser mais prático não utilizar os parâmetros, é um risco, pois permite SQL Injection, além de possíveis problemas de sintaxe ao inserir um texto com aspas por exemplo. Recomendo a utilização dos parâmetros.